# How to write back data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Accounts Controller` that has many `Tickets`

`Tickets` belongs to `account` and `tickets` accepts nested attributes for `accounts`

in `account` is a setting for the next `ticket` number `ticket_no`

so i created a function in tickets model as follows

```
  def store_ticket_no
    number = self.account.ticket_no
    if !self.ticket_no
      self.ticket_no = number
      number += 1
    end
```

How do I write back the number once incremented I tried number.save but there is no save method ?
Thanks!

Comment: so this is a method that you'll call on `ticket` - like `@ticket.store_ticket_no`?  if so it should be in `ticket.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with

```
self.account.update_attribute(:ticket_no , number)
```

is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Just remember that when you use update_attribute, you're skipping any validations and callbacks you have in your Account model. The update_attributes method however WILL run your validations, if that's what you want instead.

Comment: Actually, "update_attribute" WILL invoke callbacks but NOT validations. Using "update_column" will skip both callbacks and validations.

Comment: So it will in essence skip the validates presence ? of the accounts model?